# how to troubleshoot failing Automatic start by Windows Services

Tags: windows, service

The Windows Services UI is able to successfully start a service (Apache) manually.

However, when the service Startup Type is configured as Automatic or "Automatic (Delayed Start)", the service fails to automatically start after restarting Windows (via "shutdown /r").

When automatic start fails, the Event Viewer contains a generic "Incorrect function" message, which we saw previously with a different Services automatic start issue for another service (Wildfly).

For this issue, Apache Loglevel debug does not seem to provide any useful logging.

Since the Windows Services UI is able to successfully start the service manually, are there any logs/tips/tricks/hints for troubleshooting automatic Services start ?

Comment: What are the dependent services for your Apache installation? May be the case that something your Apache stack depends on doesn't load up at boot. To test, I'd suggest perform a clean install on a test VM or similar and check the default behaviour before diving deeper

Comment: thanks for responding, M2065 - the two services upon which Apache is dependent are "Ancillary Function Driver for Winsock" and "TCP/IP Protocol Driver" - fyi, removing these 2 dependencies seems to allow Apache to start automatically when Windows is restarted, although I don't know if that's a valid solution